# Unable to filter values while using reactable conditional formatting

Tags: r, reactable

I am trying to use conditional formatting in reactable. So the issue I am facing here is it even formats values when they are 0 and kind of showing the output (0 shouldnt be green, it should be blank). Below is the code which I have got so far. Any inputs will be appreciated thank you.

```
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~group, ~type, ~cost,
  "group a", "type 1",           139.95,
  "group a", "type 2",           139.95,
  "group a", "type 3",           139.95,
  "group b", "type 1",           189.24,
  "group b", "type 2",           189.24,
  "group b", "type 3",           0,
  "group c", "type 1",           160.26,
  "group c", "type 2",           160.26,
  "group c", "type 3",           160.26,
  "group d", "type 1",           0,
  "group d", "type 2",           185.02,
  "group d", "type 3",           185.02,
  "group e", "type 1",           204.95,
  "group e", "type 2",           204.95,
  "group e", "type 3",           204.95,
  "group f", "type 1",            0,
  "group f", "type 2",            69.35,
  "group f", "type 3",            69.35
)

df1$cost <- as.numeric(df1$cost)
df2 <-df1 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = cost)


GnYlRd <- function(x) rgb(colorRamp(c("#63be7b", "#ffeb84", "#f87274"))(x), maxColorValue = 255)
reactable(
  df2,
  defaultColDef = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
      if (!is.numeric(value)) return()
      normalized <- (value - min(df1$cost)) / (max(df1$cost) - min(df1$cost))
      color <- GnYlRd(normalized)
      list(background = color)
    },
    format = colFormat(digits = 1),
    minWidth = 50
  ),
  columns = list(
    .rownames = colDef(name = "Year", sortable = TRUE, align = "left")
  ),
  bordered = TRUE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your column's `style` function, you can check if the cell value is 0, and return `NULL` (for no styling) if so:

```
colDef(
  style = function(value) {
    if (value == 0) {
      return()
    }
    # Otherwise, continue styling the cell
  }
)
```

For example:

```
library(reactable)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~group, ~type, ~cost,
  "group a", "type 1",           139.95,
  "group a", "type 2",           139.95,
  "group a", "type 3",           139.95,
  "group b", "type 1",           189.24,
  "group b", "type 2",           189.24,
  "group b", "type 3",           0,
  "group c", "type 1",           160.26,
  "group c", "type 2",           160.26,
  "group c", "type 3",           160.26,
  "group d", "type 1",           0,
  "group d", "type 2",           185.02,
  "group d", "type 3",           185.02,
  "group e", "type 1",           204.95,
  "group e", "type 2",           204.95,
  "group e", "type 3",           204.95,
  "group f", "type 1",            0,
  "group f", "type 2",            69.35,
  "group f", "type 3",            69.35
)

df1$cost <- as.numeric(df1$cost)
df2 <-df1 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = cost)

GnYlRd <- function(x) rgb(colorRamp(c("#63be7b", "#ffeb84", "#f87274"))(x), maxColorValue = 255)

reactable(
  df2,
  defaultColDef = colDef(
    style = function(value) {
      if (!is.numeric(value) || value == 0) return()
      normalized <- (value - min(df1$cost)) / (max(df1$cost) - min(df1$cost))
      color <- GnYlRd(normalized)
      list(background = color)
    },
    format = colFormat(digits = 1),
    minWidth = 50
  ),
  columns = list(
    .rownames = colDef(name = "Year", sortable = TRUE, align = "left")
  ),
  bordered = TRUE
)
```

Also, if you want to exclude 0 from the color scale, you can do that as well like:

```
cost <- df1$cost[df1$cost > 0]
normalized <- (value - min(cost)) / (max(cost) - min(cost))
color <- GnYlRd(normalized)
```